# Add "On-Premises" Authentication to Existing ASP.Net App with Individual User Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an existing ASP.Net 4.5.1 application that I built, choosing the [Individual User Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#indauth) option for authentication with an EF-SQL back-end.  There is now a new requirement to implement [on-premise authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthonprem) for ADFS authenticated users.  These will be customer service reps that will need to be able to impersonate the individual users.  As I see it, to facilitate this I have two options:

1. Create a separate web site project utilizing on-premise authentication and configure the claims and cookies such that an authenticated ADFS user from site 2 will be authorized on site 1.  The details on how two separate sites can share claims is a bit murky to me, not to mention how the CSRs on site 2 will be able to access the ApplicationUsers from site 1.
2. Somehow add on-premise authentication to the existing site.  Not sure if this is possible.

Any advice on how to implement either would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on similar scenario, do you have any update or work around on your end ?

Comment: Sadly no.  Either nobody else is trying to do this (which I highly doubt) or nobody else has a solution.